# Trying to create a map dynamically

Tags: clojure

I wonder, why does this crash?

```
(defn test1 [var1 & var2]
  (print (json/write-str (merge {:key1 var1} var2))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (test1 "val1" {:key2 "val2" :key3 "val3"}))
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter `var2` actually contains [Rest Arguments](http://clojure.org/Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%28[params*%20]%20exprs*%29%20%29) (it comes after the `&` character). So it actually contains all the arguments that come after `var1`. You can fix the code by removing the `&`, but then you can only specify a single `var2` argument:

```
(defn test1 [var1 var2]
  (print (json/write-str (merge {:key1 var1} var2))))
```

If you want to be able to pass multiple maps as `var2`, you first have to merge them into a single map:

```
(defn test1 [var1 & var2]
  (print (json/write-str (merge {:key1 var1} 
                                (apply merge var2)))))
```

Comment: There is no need for two `merge` calls here, `(apply merger {:key1 var1} var2)` should do the job.

Comment: `into` could be used instead of `merge`, fwiw.